# I'm not able to get the value of state:{from:props.location} in Login.js

Tags: reactjs

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return props.isAuthPass === true ? (
          props.children
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

---> *This is the Login.js code*

```
//let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };

// const {state} = useLocation()
// Also props.state is not working here
// state is always undefined

if (redirectToReferrer === true) {
  return <Redirect to={state?.from || '/'} />;
}
```

Comment: Redirect is a custom component? if it is then you should be using props.state.from

Comment: Are you asking is <Redirect > is custom component or reat-router-dom component right ?

Comment: right anyway you can access the state form props.state.

Comment: No, its giving undefined, every time

Answer (score 0):

If you wrapped your main App component around BrowserRouter from 'react-router-dom' it should be passed into you your App component and you should be able to access it via props. Check in your main component if you have access to props.location. If you do, you need to pass it down to the component that is trying to access it. Than you need to add the component that requires it with 
Here is a link to help [props.location in documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location)

Comment: Are you saying : i have the access to the location in the my main app.js  file,  if i wrapped the whole app.js file with the BrowserRouter right?

Comment: Correct. BrowserRouter passes down the location prop to any component wrapped around it.

Comment: i have wrapped the app.js with the BrowserRouter in index.js file.  but i have no access to this.props.location in app.js

Comment: <Login
        authenticate = {this.signin}
        loc = {this.props.location}
        />

Comment: I'm sending the location from app.js to Login.js, which should be accessible now in app.js component as you say above, sorry if I understand it wrong, but I think I'm doing something wrong or I have missed something. Please correct me

Comment: Ok seems you need to wrap the component that needs access to props.location than with the <Route> component from react-router-dom I will edit the post with a link.